# DialogFragment does not get removed

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I create a DialogFragment using this code

```
Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_SUBMISSIOIN_RESPONSE);
AlertDialogFragment alert = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(text, getString(R.string.worklog_alert_ok));
alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_SUBMISSIOIN_RESPONSE);
```

where AlertDialogFragment is a simple DialogFragment class that creates new AlertDialog.Builder(..).

Then I want to remove the dialog

```
Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(dialogTag);
if (prev != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(prev).commit();
}
Log.d(TAG, "dialog removed " + getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(dialogTag) + ", isremoving = " + prev.isRemoving());
```

However, in the last Log.d message I still get that fragment (i.e. `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(dialogTag)` is not null, but returns valid fragment).

How do I force the dialog to be removed instantly? This is important for me, because I have the code that is executed after this function and it checks if the dialog exists, then does nothing, if does not exist, then re-creates it. However, it never re-creates it, because `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(dialogTag)` returns valid `DialogFragment`.

I am using Android compatibility package, Android version 2.2

Comment: if your `dialog` is an extension of `DialogFragment` then call `dismiss()` on the dialog fragment to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `executePendingTransactions()` immediately after `commit()`. This will force the transaction to be executed immediately. Calling `commit()` only schedules a transaction to happen in the future, so that is likely the problem that you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `transaction.remove(prev).commitAllowingStateLoss()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can show and hide fragment dialog for your processes like:

```
 public void showLoadingDialog() {
      LoadingDialogFragment fragment = (LoadingDialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LoadingDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
      if (fragment == null) {
         fragment = new LoadingDialogFragment();
         fragment.setCancelable(false);
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .add(fragment, LoadingDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG)
                                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();

         // fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), LoadingDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
      }
   }

   public void hideLoadingDialog() {
      LoadingDialogFragment fragment = (LoadingDialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LoadingDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
      if (fragment != null) {
         // fragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
      }
   }
```

i think this'll help you.